# How to get the latest file of certain pattern created in a directory

Tags: c#, file

I could get the latest created by using this below; but I want the latest created with certain  pattern, not just the latest created

```
 var directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\my_dir\\dir_1\\dir_2\\");
        var smf_log_name = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, can't you do this `directory.GetFiles("myPattern").OrderByDescending...`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, can you give example.

Comment: @keyboardP: According to the docs, the string parameter is a path, not a pattern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Only if using the Directory class, but the DirectoryInfo class only has the search pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx (and another overload for directory depth).

Comment: @keyboardP: nice. it works.

Comment: @keyboardP: Ah, right you are.  Got thrown by the `directory` name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I did the same thing :D I initially typed out the `Directory` overload (with path and search string) as that's what I see more often but realised just before posting.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8he88b63(v=vs.100).aspx) has an overload that takes a pattern argument

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\my_dir\\dir_1\\dir_2");
var smf_log_name = directory.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Pay attention to the pattern passed, if there are no files with the pattern specified the sequence will throw an `InvalidOperationException`

```
FileInfo result = null;
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\my_dir\\dir_1\\dir_2");
var list = directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
if(list.Count() > 0)
{
    result = list.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search pattern in the `GetFiles` method.

```
directory.GetFiles("myPattern").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

You can also use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` if you want all the subdirectories to be included in the search.

```
directory.GetFiles("myPattern", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```