# Identify the latest file through specific patterns in a directory

Tags: c#

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\example");
string pattern = "LOG" + "_" + "NA" + "_" + "3465";
var validFiles = directory.GetFiles("*.xml");

List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in validFiles)
{
   string a = item.ToString();
   if (a.Contains(pattern))
   {
      list.Add(a);
   }
}
```

I wanted to get the latest file with the above pattern from the directory specified. I had tried the as above to get the file that as the common pattern, but, I am stuck in getting the latest file among the files in `<list>`. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can sort the list before use foreach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981720/how-to-get-the-latest-file-of-certain-pattern-created-in-a-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another one with bit more steps:

```
var d=new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\logs");//Main Directory
var files=d.GetFiles("*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);//Get .txt files
var patt=@"error-2016-09-"; //Pattern to search in file name

var matching = files.OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreationTimeUtc)
                       .Where(f => f.FullName.Contains(patt));

var latest=matching.First();//gets error-2016-09-29.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help buddy.. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern when you call `GetFiles`, then order by creation date or whatever field you're interested in. The `OrderByDescending` ensures the oldest file is on top.

```
list = directory.GetFiles("*LOG_NA_3465*.xml")
                .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTime)
                .First();
```

In your code, by the time you store the results in the `List<string>`, you're not dealing with a `FileInfo` object anymore and you've lost access to any details about the files.